# file_get_contents отдает пустой результат

Tags: php, steam

```
switch ($p) {
    case 'login':
        include 'openid.php';
        try
        {
            $openid = new LightOpenID('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/');
            if (!$openid->mode) {
                $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid/?l=russian';
                header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
            } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
                echo '';
            } else {
                if ($openid->validate()) {

                    $id = $openid->identity;
                    $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                    preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                    $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=E7AE7AAE3CB43A2A642C855ACA4FE117&steamids=$matches[1]";
                    $json_object = file_get_contents($url);
                    $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
                    die($url);
                    foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player) {
                        $steamid = $player->steamid;
                        $name = $player->personaname;
                        $avatar = $player->avatarfull;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ErrorException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
        break;

    default:
        header('location: /main');
        exit();
        break;
}
```

`$json_object = file_get_contents($url);` - отдает пустой результат.

Проверял так, после строчки `$json_object = file_get_contents($url);` ставил `die($json_object)` - результат пустая страница, `$url` же передается и выводится нормально.

`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=E7AE7AAE3CB43A2A642C855ACA4FE117&steamids=76561198222889260` вот валидный `$url` .

Как правильно задебажить и выяснить в чем именно проблема? Мучаюсь уже второй день

Comment: @Jean-Claude http://f6.s.qip.ru/GjeazSvW.png die(var_dump($matches));

Comment: В плане сделал это в скрипте? чтобы зайти на сайт, надо авторизоваться на платформе. Просто тут суть в том, что даже если я  matches - заменю на конкретный steamid, то результат будет тот же

Comment: ну так смотрите, $id вы получили через класс LightOpenID(), он видимо для авторизации, а парсить пытаетесь напрямую через file_get_contents, без авторизации, ищите существуют ли в этом классе LightOpenID методы парсинга.

Comment: @Jean-Claude там подключена библиотека openid https://gist.github.com/kiLLro/899b2e34375090ab8b1a4a0e5dc3d156

Comment: насчет авторизации к джейсону ошибался, он же идет через ключ, курл работает отлично http://ideone.com/QYXv28 (ключ кстати светить нельзя)

Comment: @Jean-Claude ключ изменю все равно. http://f3.s.qip.ru/GjeazSvY.png вывел код в отдельную страницу - 500 ошибку вообще выдает

Comment: с моим кодом ошибка? ты заметил что там урл подзатерся троеточиями? (если нажать редактировать, то он показывается полностью)

Comment: http://f6.s.qip.ru/GjeazSvZ.png

Comment: Может у меня хост это как-то блочит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, в коде ничего не менял. Оказывается у меня не был установлен php-curl.

Выполнил команду `apt-get install php-curl`, перезагрузил сервер и все заработало!